# Increasing the quality of the edited image in adobe creative SDK

Tags: android, image-editing, adobecreativesdk

I have this code to launch the adobe creative SDK image editor.

```
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);

        Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
                .setData(imageUri)
                .build();

        startActivityForResult(imageEditorIntent, 1);
```

I want the edited image be in highest quality.

What Intent parameters be passed for that ? Or any other workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Example from the Image Editor guide

You can set the image quality with the Image Editor's optional methods. Here is an example from the [Creative SDK's Image Editor guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html#methods):

```
Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
    .setData(uri) // input image source
    .withOutput(Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/my-pic-name.jpg")) // output file destination
    .withOutputFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG) // output format
    .withOutputSize(MegaPixels.Mp5) // output size
    .withOutputQuality(90) // output quality
    .build();
```

In your case, you might mostly be interested in `.withOutputSize()` and `.withOutputQuality()`.

## Relevant optional methods

From the Image Editor guide:

- `.withOutputSize(MegaPixels)`

  > Sets the output file size (in megapixels).
  >
  > If this method is not called, or a value of 0 is passed, then the preview sized image will be returned (usually the screen size of the device).

  **Note:** you can pass in any value from the Creative SDK's `MegaPixels` enum, `Mp0` to `Mp30`.
- `.withOutputQuality(int)`

  > If the outputformat is JPEG, defines the quality of the saved JPEG image.

  **Note:** for maximum quality, pass in `100`.

## Documentation for all optional methods

For details on the methods above and all other optional methods, you can refer to [this section of the Creative SDK Image Editor guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html#methods).

Comment: Unfortunately CreativeSDK was closed in April 2017. There is no more access to the documentation, guides, etc.